# TruncatedSVD - Explained Variance

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For `RandomizedPCA` in `sci-kit learn`, I can see the variance explained by each component in the `explained_variance_ratio_` attribute.  Is there something equivalent I can get from `TruncatedSVD`?  I want to know if it's worthwhile getting `TruncatedSVD` to return more components.

Note: I don't even know if the concept of 'explained variance' applies to the `TruncatedSVD` technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to check but even the `explained_variance_ratio_` of `RandomizedPCA` might be broken. I don't think there is a principled way to compute it when you truncate the SVD.

**Edit**: I just checked in [this notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ogrisel/notebooks/blob/master/Explained%20variances.ipynb) by computing the true explained variance rate from the data and indeed `RandomizedPCA` is lying.

In the end if you want to compute the true explained variance you can do it from the data:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

model = TruncatedSVD(n_components=10).fit(X)
X_proj = model.transform(X)
explained_variances = np.var(X_proj, axis=0) / np.var(X, axis=0).sum()
```

**Second edit**: I reported the issue here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2663

Comment: Would this method make sense?  Say I start with a training set of 0.5mil dimensions.  I perform TruncatedSVD to get it down to 200 components.  Each principal component is a linear combination of the old features (0.5 mil of them).  For each of the old features, I sum the absolute coefficient (aka loadings I think) over each of the new components and I interpret this sum as an "importance score".  Plot this "importance score" for each original feature and based on the where the "elbow" of the graph is, determine whether I need more components.

Make sense or non-sense?

Comment: Compute the explained variances empirically as I explained in my edit and look for your elbow or an threshold (e.g. keep only the first components to reach 75% of the variance). That should work.